# What models currently support multivariate regression in tidymodels?

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-recipes, r-parsnip

I was checking tidymodels for multivariate regression and saw this example here:
https://www.tidymodels.org/learn/models/pls/

This covers multivariate for Partial Least Squares model.
Is there a page that states what models currently support multivariate regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the current models that support multivariate (more than one outcome) regression are:

- [single layer neural network: `mlp()`](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/mlp.html)
- [multivariate adaptive regression splines: `mars()`](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/mars.html)
- good old [linear regression: `linear_reg()`](https://parsnip.tidymodels.org/reference/linear_reg.html)

This list was made by [looking for which models use the `maybe_multivariate()` internal helper](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/search?q=maybe_multivariate), but we should document this better somehow.

Comment: I opened an issue to [track this here](https://github.com/tidymodels/parsnip/issues/798).